# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'BatchDataset' and 'float'. I can't load unlabeled images from google drive using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, image-preprocessing

I am using Tensorflow. I want to load unlabeled images from google drive and then ***normalize*** them. However, when I run this code

```
data_train_gan = (data_train_gan - 127.5) / 127.5  # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
```

I see error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'BatchDataset' and 'float'.**

Full code:

```
import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path("gdrive/MyDrive/projects/images/rock/")

data_train_gan = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  label_mode=None,
  image_size=(height, width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

data_train_gan = (data_train_gan - 127.5) / 127.5  # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To apply a function to each element of a `tf.data.Dataset`, you should use the [`map` method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map). It takes a callable (like a function) as a first argument.

```
def normalize(image):
    return (image - 127.5) / 127.5

normalized_dataset = data_train_gan.map(normalize)
```

Note that in your case, you might have to cast your input to tf.float32 before normalization (you can do that with [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast))

Comment: When I try to use this function, I face the following error: `TypeError: 'MapDataset' object is not subscriptable`. But when I use tf.cast, I have this: `ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<BatchDataset shapes: (None, 64, 64, 3), types: tf.float32>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>) to a Tensor`.  Are there any other methods to load _unlabeled_ images from google drive to the model?

Comment: `TypeError: 'MapDataset' object is not subscriptable` this indiates that you are trying to access a subscript of `normalized_datataset` (for example `normalized_dataset[i]`). You can't do that. Read the [guide about tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data). Furthermore, if you want to cast, you would need to do it in the `normalize` function.